# Android 'Smart Display' and issues with AIR/Camera Interactions

Tags: android, air, camera

I'm in the process of attempting to use the camera and some motion tracking AS3 classes to detect movement in front of a ViewSonic Smart Display, for the sake of a demo. I've gotten the app and detection to function on other Android devices, but the 'Smart Display' is presenting me with some odd issues.

Taking a long shot that someone might've encountered this, but this is the very simple camera set up code I reduced the issue down to:

```
var camera = Camera.getCamera();
camera.setMode(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, 30, true);
var video:Video = new Video(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
video.attachCamera(camera);
```

My problem lies at the point of "video.attachCamera"
For some reason, this device takes this function as "Display the video in a tiny window in the upper right hand corner" and ignores all other code, dominating the screen with blank black, and a tiny (maybe 40x20px square) of video stream.

Image of it occuring...
[image]

Any help is much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be the values that you are passing to the camera with the `setMode()` method. You are trying to set the camera to capture at the width/height of the stage.

The camera likely does not have such a capture resolution, and as the [documentation for setMode()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setMode%28%29) states, it will try to find something that is close to what you have specified:

> Sets the camera capture mode to the native mode that best meets the specified requirements. If the camera does not have a native mode that matches all the parameters you pass, the runtime selects a capture mode that most closely synthesizes the requested mode. This manipulation may involve cropping the image and dropping frames.

Now, it is granted that you would expect Flash to have picked a resolution that is bigger than what is shown in your screenshot. But given the myriad of camera devices/drivers, it's possible this is not working too well in your case.

You might start off by experimenting w/more typical resolutions to capture the video: 480x320, 640x480, 800x600, or at the most 1024x768. Most applications on the web probably use the first or second capture resolutions.

So change:

```
camera.setMode(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, 30, true);
```

To:

```
camera.setMode(640, 480, 30, true);
```

Note you can display the video in any size you want, but the capture resolutions you can use depend on your camera hardware/drivers/OS/etc. Typical resolutions have a 4:3 aspect ratio and are relatively small (not the full dimensions of the screen/stage). The capture resolution you use affects the quality of video and the amount of network bandwidth you need to stream the video. Generally (for streaming), you **don't** want to use a big capture resolution, but maybe it's not so important in your motion capture use case.

Comment: Gave that a shot, same thing. Even removing the setMode() method had no effect. At a loss, as this same application works in almost every other Android or PC I run it on.

Comment: @Kaalamity bummers... did you try various resolution sizes? I looked up the specs on that ViewSonic Smart Display, it says the camera does 720p video, so I can't imagine it having issues w/"standard" capture resolutions. I'm curious: from your screen shot it looks like Flash is cropping the video (rather than showing the whole video at some smaller size), is that correct? Finally, I think the fact that it works properly everywhere else, points to something device/hardware specific (check for updated drivers if possible). Can you plug in a USB camera and try that?

Comment: As soon as I can get my hands on an external camera, I'll give that a shot. And its hard to tell in that image, but the video is actually shrunk down that small. Can see myself waving and such.

Regretfully, I do believe it is the hardware, and their custom drivers, was more just hoping it wasn't, and that someone might've encountered something similar!